# How should I go about a long JavaScript file using the module pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I am learning design pattern in JavaScript, and I'm going to use the module pattern. I'm puzzled with two things.

1 - If I would create a plugin, then I can use the module pattern, and have private and public methods/variables. But if I have a full JavaScript file, I don't need private and public methods, since one part of the program has nothing to do with another part. So what's the point of private and public methods?

2 - Since the JavaScript file is really long, should I have nested module's? How should I go about a full file of JavaScript?

Comment: Can someone explain why 2 people voted to close the question "because it' opinion based."? I'm asking for an explanation. I don't think it's opinion based...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "plug-in". Plug-in to what?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has moved on. ES6--which there is no real reason not to move up to, if you haven't already--has its own modules. So there is no need to "simulate" modules with old patterns. Example:

```
// Old style.
var myModule = function() {
  var privateVar;
  function getPrivateVar() { return privateVar; }
  return {getPrivateVar: getPrivateVar};
}();

console.log(myModule.getPrivateVar());

// New style.
let privateVar;
function getPrivateVar() { return privateVar; }
export {privateVar};

// Using it
import {getPrivateVar} from './myModule';
console.log(getPrivateVar());
```

In the above, `privateVar` is by definition private to the module (file). There's no need to keep it private by wrapping it in an IIFE. Instead of handling the exports ourselves as properties of a single returned object, we use the ES6 export mechanism to export it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

(1)

When all Javascript files are loaded, all the scripts in all files are just like they are in one file. Script in one file can access (read, update, delete) **global variables** in other files. There are a lot of questions on this, you can easily search for those.

Of course, "one part of the program has nothing to do with another part", but in case you are in team with many members, each works on a part of the system (or in some cases, a file). Then, there is a chance that one person accidentally changes variables created by another person. Those kinds of error are quite easy to detect. But if you can modularize you script, you can avoid those kinds of error altogether.

(2)

You can go slow. While writing code to complete requirements, try to recognize the parts of code that can be separated to a modules (or even nested modules). Them put them into other files.

You should be creative and careful while doing so. The code might grow very fast and things get out of control very quickly.